# Replace CR by CR LF

Tags: text

I'm on Windows and I have an odd text file containing mostly CR+LF line ending. A *few* lines end with only CR. Which tool to use to transform these odd lines into well formatted (e.g. CR+LF terminated) lines?

I could use either GnuWin32 tools or Python to solve this.

The main problem I have is that I cannot open the file as text file since Python (as most other text processors, such as awk) don't recognize the mixed line endings. So I believe the solution must incorporate binary processing of the file.

The again, I cannot just replace CR by CR LF, since there are also CR LF line endings existing that must not be touched.

Comment: You might try Notepad++.  It handles "odd" files pretty well, and has tools within to fix up the oddities.

Comment: +1 for Notepad++ I use it all the time for things like this.

Comment: Are you able to use any other language except from Python? It would be no problem to implement this in Java

Comment: As I posted, it should be done with a tool that can be used in a script, either GnuWin32 tools or Python. Nothing else is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace lines you can use regular expressions:

- `\r+` to find CR
- `\r\n` is the text you want as replacement text.

---

Regular Expressions in Python:
[Regular Expression](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html)

---

```
import re
txt='text where you want to replace the linebreak'
out = re.sub("\r+", '\r\n', txt)
print out
```

Comment: It does the trick if using just [\r]+ as regular expression to search for (see my original question: I need to replace CR by CR+LF).

Comment: won't it will also replace preexisting `\r\n` by `\r\r\n`?